# SVG from web to print

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, coldfusion

I am developing an online restaurant menu editor. The template is SVG, with a jpeg image of the menu as the background. The user is able to edit the text which is SVG text elements laid on top of the template image.

I am able to create a PDF from this SVG, for the user to see, just fine. Now I want to drop the low resolution background image out of the SVG and place the remaining text into a high resolution print, ready pdf for printing. The problem is the text does not appear in the right place in the print ready file. Nor is it the same size.

I am using the ColdFusion `CFPdf`tag to place the text using the watermark feature. I have tested this and it works fine. It's just the size and coordinates that are off. I know this is because of the resolution but how do I get it to work? There might even be a better way, I don't know.

Comment: You may have more control over the contents of the pdf file with `cfdocument`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on your thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on your code i.e. provide a [mcve] in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I needed to change the viewport in the svg to the actual size of the hi res pdf instead of leaving it at the low res pixel size I had it at for the web.

Comment: I would like to know more about what you are doing for web svg to print. contactomarnow@gmail.com